# #region functionality in SSMS 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, region

Using Sql Server 2008, is there any functionality similar to #region in Visual Studio?

I'm aware that nodes appear to allow collapsing of SQL segments, but as far as I know, this is based on the syntax of the SQL statement.

While that is close to what I'm after, I'm wondering if there is a way to define a section of code, regardless of syntax, similar to #region/#endregion.

Any thoughts?

Comment: IMHO you should consider keeping scripts short enough.

Comment: But that may not be always possible

Comment: stored procedures can get really large sometimes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an add-in for SSMS called [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/).
It lets you use #region / #endregion  http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=9

Comment: Collapses region only if you select the block and press `CTRL + K + J`

Answer (score 11):

Yes, there is native support in SSMS 2008 on, without any addins.
The regions are defined by:

1. From first GO command to next GO command.
2. Statements between BEGIN – END, BEGIN TRY – END TRY, BEGIN CATCH – END CATCH
3. Multiline statements

See examples here:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/06/28/sql-server-2008-management-studio-new-features-2/

Answer (score 3):

I develop SSMSBoost add-in (www.ssmsboost.com) for SSMS and have added

```
--#region [name]
--#endregion
```

syntax support in last version (2.12). There is also an option to auto-parse opened files, so that regions will be displayed immediately.

Answer (score 3):

I have just been hacking the `begin`, `end` to create regions as shown below:

```
begin--region Getting top 5 Employee records
    select top 5 * from dbo.Employee order by Salary;
end--region Getting top 5 Employee records
```

I always make sure to put the `--region` beside the `begin` and `end` so they stand out from real `begin` and `end` blocks. For example:

```
if (1=1)
begin
    begin--region Getting top 5 Employee records
        select top 5 * from dbo.Employee order by Salary;
    end--region Getting top 5 Employee records
end
```

Answer (score 0):

No there's not.  It only is done at the statement level.